# Caracter & no es reconocido al realizar select a base de datos mysql

Tags: php, android, mysqli

Buen día por favor tengo un problema al realizar un select a mi base de datos SQL, ya que no me reconoce el carácter '&' en la consulta y por ende no me devuelve los registros consultados. Les agradezco que me colaboren.

Comment: Hola JVega, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Puedes mostrarnos tu consulta actual asi como datos de ejemplo sobre la que aplicarla? Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Dónde usas el carácter `&` en tu consulta y para qué lo usas? Para poder ayudarte mejor sería conveniente que pusieras tu consulta, [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/160892/edit).

Comment: Es que el registro que quiero consultar y que esta en la base de datos, contiene un carácter '&' en su nombre y la consulta no encuentra el registro por que no reconoce el carácter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el problema al que te enfrentas es que el registro tiene "&" en algún nombre o en alguna tabla la solución podría ser utilizando:

```
SELECT * FROM "foo&foo";
```

En caso de que necesites una sentencia de php para llamar a la sentencia SQL debería ser algo similar a esto:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM "foo&foo"';
```

De todas formas te recomiendo que subas código para que podamos dar una respuesta en condiciones y no unas respuestas tan poco concretas como las que acabo de darte.

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT id_empresa, paquete_empresa, categoria_empresa, nombre_empresa from guia where id_empresa=? and nombre_empresa=?';

Comment: Este es el select que realizo a la base de datos

Comment: El problema radica en que nombre_empresa no se reconoce para un registro de base de datos que se llama "R&M".

Comment: Sin una imagen de tu BBDD para poder hacerme una idea de como está configurado te recomendaría cambiar el nombre del registor, lo más probable es que no reconozca ese registro porque el caracter "&" ya es un caracter reservado de sistema que se utiliza para marcar "AND". Aún así, sigo insistiendo en que edites tu publicación original y nos muestres como tienes montada la BBDD, que consulta haces, que respuesta te da etc.

Comment: Anion es mejor no responder a preguntas que no tienen la calidad o la informacion necesaria. Sin que lo aclare no sabes que le puede estar sucediendo. Un saludo